# Should we encourage Q&A Sessions in the Chat page?

Tags: discussion

Something that I don't see people do often, is setting up live Q&A chat sessions on Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow has a very good Q&A Model, but when an insufficient question is asked, it is simply downvoted into oblivion.

This doesn't help the original poster with his or her question. So recently, if I've got an hour spare, I've opened up a chat room and offered to talk the issue through with OP. This has lead to some very successful sessions with OP and helped them come to their conclusions. I have also told them to first close their question.

Should I be doing this? Is this a good thing to do, or should I be encouraging them to ask another, more comprehensive question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this a good thing to do, or should I be encouraging them to ask another, more comprehensive question?

It doesn't harm and it provides the OP with an answer/solution to their problem. Chat transcripts are also indexed by google, so they are also available to the public.

However - it can be much harder to discern the actual question and answer from the back-and-forth that are characteristic of chats, even with the conversation thread support our chat has.

I would suggest that once a good solution/answer has been reached, post a question and answer pair, linking to the chat transcript and possibly the original question - so the end result is easily found and understood.

You can either post both yourself, or in conjunction with the OP.

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines. Thanks for the response! +1